# Possible to have composite component inside a dialog in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, composite

Is it possible to have the composite component inside a dialog in primefaces? I have done the code but it seems like the composite component cannot be rendered in the dialog as what I wish to achieve. When I triggered the show dialog, nothing comes out.

Dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="editManageDealDialogId" styleClass="pf-dialog"
    responsive="true" closable="false" resizable="false" modal="true"
    widgetVar="editManageDealWidgetVar">
    <util:placement-deal id="newDPCompositeId"
        formHeader="Edit deposit placement"></util:placement-deal>
</p:dialog>
```

Composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<h:head></h:head>

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="formHeader" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h:form id="form-modal" styleClass="my-form">
           <p:outputLabel value="Testing"></p:outputLabel>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you open that dialog? Any JS errors?

Comment: i open the dialog with PF('editManageDealWidgetVar').show();
I do try to put the composite component outside of the dialog and its working :(
Have you tried with this before?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. gain, any JS errors? See Chrome > Console

Comment: Nope, no single JS errors found as well. Weird. :(

Comment: Does it work outside the dialog? And why is there an `h:head` inside the composite? That is not right... And using a form inside the composite is dangerous. Risk of getting nested forms

Comment: Yes it is working outside of the dialog meant i am actually putting this dialog in one xhtml and if i move the composite to outside of the dialog then it is working fine.I mistaken to put the head actually, but its actually wont caused any issue right? Is better to make the form outside of the dialog as well to avoid nested forms?